# Creating pivot table in pandas with different functions for each value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

This is my code and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Edit: It says name 'count' not defined

```
df1.pivot_table(index=["Unit", "Grade"],values = ["Cost", "Quantity","Transaction_num", "Order_num"], aggfunc={'Cost':[np.sum],'Quantity':[np.sum], "Transaction_num":[count],"Order_num":[count]})
```

I want a sum of total cost and total quantity but I want a distinct count of transaction number and order number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you forgot a parenthesis. Properly indenting code helps ;)

```
df1.pivot_table(index=['Unit', 'Grade'],
                values=['Cost', 'Quantity', 'Transaction_num', 'Order_num'],
                aggfunc={'Cost': 'sum',
                         'Quantity': 'sum',
                         'Transaction_num': 'count',
                         'Order_num': 'count',
                        }
               )
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the help. However, now I get a new error saying name 'count' is not defined

Comment: @alwayzconfused I was fixing it, check the update

Comment: what do I need to do if I want to find unique count of the last two values?